# Why doesn't this program short circuit?

Tags: awk, logical-operators

Running gnu awk I get a div/0 error. Mawk does not have the same error.

```
>>> awk 'BEGIN { print (0 && (4/0)) }'
awk: cmd. line:1: error: division by zero attempted
>>> mawk ''BEGIN { print (0 && (4/0)) }'
0
```

If I add parenthesis around the 4 it behaves the same

```
>>> awk "BEGIN { print (0 && ((4)/0)) }"
0
>>> mawk "BEGIN { print (0 && ((4)/0)) }"
0
```

Which seems like it should not matter.

Looking through the [posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) I can't actually find the words short circuiting, so are both correct? Just mawk?

[GNU awk does say this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Boolean-Ops.html)

> The ‘&&’ and ‘||’ operators are called short-circuit operators because of the way they work. Evaluation of the full expression is “short-circuited” if the result can be determined partway through its evaluation.

Comment: Both are correct and would have the same behavior at run time (see [@jhnc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347579/1745001) but gawk while internally optimizing your code **before running it** tells you that you have a leg which, if reached, would cause a divide by zero error. So, given a 1TB input file with a script that has a similar divide by zero in the END section, gawk would fail immediately while mawk would apparently wait til it had been running for 3 hours and THEN tell you :-).

Answer (score 6):

By default, gawk optimises code with [constant-folding](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awkgram.y?h=gawk-5.1-stable#n5478).
This happens before the program is run.

It can be turned off with `-s`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { 0 && 4/0; print "ok" }'
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: division by zero attempted
$ gawk -s 'BEGIN { 0 && 4/0; print "ok" }'
ok
$
```

Comment: those 2 concepts shouldn't be mutually exclusive - gawk can constant fold all it wants, but it should store up the exceptions thrown, and only actually throw them out as a fatal error when the evaluation reaches that part. besides, div-by-zero should be simply be an warning instead of being fatal, given what Wolfram Alpha calls `"complex infinity"` is a valid use case of such a scenario.

Comment: @jhnc as you mention the error report is due to constant folding and I'm happy they do it since I'd want to know if I had a line of code that would always divides by zero, but I brought the difference between `(4)/0` and `4/0` up to the gawk providers and they'll now have a fix for the `print (0 && ((4)/0))` case and other similar constructs that evaluate to constants NOT producing the error message in an upcoming gawk release (watch for it in upcoming release notes).

Comment: You can see the upcoming patch at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2022-08/msg00028.html if you care.

Comment: So is the conclusion here that both are correct behavior? I understand how constant folding vs not changes when the error occurs but these seem like significantly different behaviors. Are they both compatible with the standard?

Comment: @nlta An gawk program that runs will shortcircuit. However, gawk won't let you run some programs (such as your example) when it has not been told not to optimise.

Comment: [The issue of `print (0 && ((4)/0))` not failing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347380/why-doesnt-this-program-short-circuit/73347579#comment129540726_73347579) is fixed in gawk version 5.2 such that a denominator of constant 0 will always produce a pre-run error message unless code optimization is deactivated by the `-s` argument.